# Floor standing vertically mounted server?

Tags: nas, computer-building

Is it possible to have a server standing vertically so the front is at the top? My plan for heat is simply to reverse the direction of the fans so it's pulling air from the bottom (back) and out the top (front) of the case.

The problem I have so far is I can't find any way of mounting a server in this position aside from wall mounts. The issue I have with that is I'd strongly prefer not to have this permanently mounted to a wall. An open frame would be ideal but I can't find anything that fits.

Suggestions and criticisms welcome!

Comment: IIRC, most commercially available rackmount servers work the other way. They pull in air from the front.

Comment: Most do, yeah, but it's an easy thing to reverse fans and from a thermal perspective pulling back to front vs. front to back is going to be functionally identical. Maybe I'm putting a few degrees more heat over the drives after it passes the CPU but the air moving through the system isn't going to be so hot as to risk toasting any components. It's also going to spend most of it's life idling anyway.

Comment: Fan blades are designed to work in one direction efficiently, reversing them may not move the same volume of air.

Comment: Which is fine, it's not going to be locked in a poorly ventilated closet nor is it going to be doing heavy loads on a regular basis. I am not in the least bit concerned with thermals, that is a problem that's very easy to tackle.

Comment: The best suggestion I've gotten so far was from the office IT guy who said, "Get an open frame, turn it on it's end. It'll support it just fine."